# org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jasypt

I'm using the Jasypt encryption library to encrypt/decrypt some text.  This code is embedded in a WAR file and deployed to a server.

When running locally, and in unit tests, the encrypt/decrypt cycle works perfectly.  I use Jetty to develop the application.  The code works perfectly in that server.  For some reason, deploying to Tomcat breaks it with the following exception:

FYI, I have the strong encryption libraries installed in both my local and server environments and I'm using the latest 1.6 version (patch level 25).

**org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException**

The exception has no message.

The code is fully symmetric.  I pasted it here for examination.  Here are the relevant bits:

I found one [old Nabble post](http://old.nabble.com/At-my-wits-end---EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException-td18470285.html) where a user had a very similar problem.  Code worked everywhere except inside Tomcat.  No solution was given.

Any insights would be most appreciated.

**Update: ** Running in Tomcat on my local system, it appears to work.  So there's something about my server.  On the server, I'm using a 64-bit JVM on Windows Server 2008.  I'm using a 32-bit JVM locally (due to my system being a bit older).  I wonder if this has something to do with the issue.

```
public void initializeService() {
    binaryEncryptor = new BasicBinaryEncryptor();
    binaryEncryptor.setPassword(keyBase64);
}

@Override
public <T extends Serializable> String simpleEncrypt(T objectToEncrypt) throws EncryptionException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(objectToEncrypt);

        byte[] bytes = binaryEncryptor.encrypt(bos.toByteArray());
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("failed to encrypt String: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new EncryptionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("failed to encrypt String: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new EncryptionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> T simpleDecrypt(String objectToDecrypt) throws EncryptionException {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(objectToDecrypt);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = binaryEncryptor.decrypt(bytes);

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedBytes));
        T object = (T)ois.readObject();
        return object;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("failed to decrypt String: '" + objectToDecrypt + "', mesage = " + e.getMessage());
        throw new EncryptionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("failed to decrypt String: '" + objectToDecrypt + "', mesage = " + e.getMessage());
        throw new EncryptionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like a confirmation - is it the decryption operation that is failing with the exception? If so, have you already checked out [this question at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905281/miffed-simple-code-but-org-jasypt-exceptions-encryptionoperationnotpossib) ?

Comment: This is an awesome comment from the docs of jayst: It is intended to provide very little information (if any) of the error causes, so that encryption internals are not revealed through error messages.

Comment: OK, I solved the problem.  I was putting the encrypted String on the URL after Base64encoding, then URLencoding the string.  In my environment, this worked fine.  On my server, where I front-end Tomcat with Apache, this didn't work.  I found an answer in the Jasypt FAQ.  I changed from Base64 encoding to Hex encoding.  This fixed it.  I'm guessing that Apache may have altered the raw query string before passing to Tomcat.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to the docs:  http://www.jasypt.org/faq.html#i-keep-on-receiving-encryption-operation-not-possible

- Is encryption and decryption config identical
- Check to make sure table columns are large enough
- Base64 encoding and urlencoding can conflict, so it has to be done just right.

Answer (score 4):

@biniam_Ethiopia 
I would have commented your answer but I have not enough reputation, so I write my own answer:

I had a very similiar problem, but in my case it was because of changing the encryption algorithm (*PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES*), while entries in the db were saved with a different one before (*PBEWithMD5AndDES*).
So I got a EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException too, which is without information because of @Nathan Feger's comment above.

I hope this could help somebody someday too ;)

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem.
For me, it was because it was trying to decrypt a password which could not have been decrypted using the decrypting mechanism.

Hence, I **encrypted the password and stored it in database** before the decrypt method tries to decrypt it.

I hope it helps someone.